# How to stop image movement

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Basically, me and my friend are working on a game review website.
There is a menu where you select the game you want to read about.

Our problem is that the games move when we resize an image (game icon) next to it. How could we stop it from moving?

Here is our code:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
    <title>
        Just a game review thing
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Doesn't have a name yet</h1>
  
    <div class="gameLinks">
      <a><img src="images/Sea_of_Thieves.png" alt="Sea of Thieves" class="gameLinkImg"></a>
      <a><img src="images/Sea_of_Thieves.png" alt="Sea of Thieves" class="gameLinkImg"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #1a202f;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Bungee;
  src: url("fonts/Bungee-Regular.ttf");
}

h1 {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: Bungee, cursive;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.gameLinks {
  margin: 0 200px;
}

.gameLinkImg {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 10%;
}

.gameLinkImg:hover {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 30px;
  width: 12%;
}
```

Comment: Why are you resizing the image?  Maybe just don't do that?

Comment: No, because it looks cool and I like resizing stuff because it makes it fun

Answer (score 0):

Instead of altering a dimension you could use a scaling function. This will not alter the positioning of other elements.

It depends on whether you want to just scale the width or whether you want the whole image to get a bit bigger as to which scaling function to use. This snippet just makes the image get bigger by a factor of 12/10.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <title>
    Just a game review thing
  </title>

  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #1a202f;
    }
    
    @font-face {
      font-family: Bungee;
      src: url("fonts/Bungee-Regular.ttf");
    }
    
    h1 {
      color: whitesmoke;
      font-family: Bungee, cursive;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 80px;
    }
    
    .gameLinks {
      margin: 0 200px;
    }
    
    .gameLinkImg {
      transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
      width: 10%;
    }
    
    .gameLinkImg:hover {
      transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
      box-shadow: 8px 8px 30px;
      transform: scale(calc(12 / 10));
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Doesn't have a name yet</h1>

  <div class="gameLinks">
    <a><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300" alt="Sea of Thieves" class="gameLinkImg"></a>
    <a><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/300" alt="Sea of Thieves" class="gameLinkImg"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="gameLinks">
    <a><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300" alt="Sea of Thieves" class="gameLinkImg"></a>
    <a><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/300" alt="Sea of Thieves" class="gameLinkImg"></a>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the function?

Comment: I used transform: scale(calc(12 / 10)) - could of course have been just transform: scale(1.2) - I just used a calc to make it plain that it was going from your 10 to 12.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It still moves the other images down

Comment: That's weird. Anyway, what other images? Could you put a bit more code into your question which shows these other images?

Comment: Are you sure you've taken the width setting in the hover out?

Comment: I've added another couple of images below the first two in the snippet to prove that they don't move when you hover over either of the first two.